# Show View Before Loading? Run Indicator While Loading?

Tags: iphone, progress-bar

I made a second xib and go from the main to that one. The thing is that the second view has a bunch of data to capture and load. When you click the button to go to the second view, the second view WILL NOT be displayed until all the data is loaded via nsxmlparser.

I want it to go to the second view immediately and then show an activity indicator on that page (second page) while it loads the data. How can I display the second xib file right on the button click, then load the data on there?

Comment: What do you mean by "data to capture and load"? Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You should tage a look at [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), that creates a seperate thread, where you can parse your XML, while it displays a prograss-bar. It's easy to implement, so just follow the guide in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to each of your UIViews and map the view in your xib to the subclass. Implement awakeFromNib in your second subclass and start a download of your data there. When finished hide your activity indicator (I assume this is already setup in your xib).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your best bet is to move the parsing in a separate thread. One way you can do that is to create a method to run/setup/load/parse the xml data, and call `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(YourMethodGoesHere) withObject:nil]`